# Outputted pdf not filling with the content in iTextsharp and C#.net, creating with Zero bytes

Tags: c#, itext

I am working to replace the specific word inside pdf document using iTextSharp and C#.net, while I am debugging getting the proper value but the outputted pdf getting zero bytes(empty),its not filling with the content.

```
ReplacePDFText("Mumbai",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase,Application.StartupPath + "\\test.pdf","D:\\test_words_replaced.pdf"); //Do Everything

public void ReplacePDFText(string strSearch, StringComparison scCase, string strSource, string strDest)
    {

        PdfStamper psStamp = null; //PDF Stamper Object
        PdfContentByte pcbContent = null; //Read PDF Content

        if (File.Exists(strSource)) //Check If File Exists
        {

            PdfReader pdfFileReader = new PdfReader(strSource); //Read Our File

            psStamp = new PdfStamper(pdfFileReader, new FileStream(strDest, FileMode.Create)); //Read Underlying Content of PDF File

            pbProgress.Value = 0; //Set Progressbar Minimum Value
            pbProgress.Maximum = pdfFileReader.NumberOfPages; //Set Progressbar Maximum Value

            for (int intCurrPage = 1; intCurrPage <= pdfFileReader.NumberOfPages; intCurrPage++) //Loop Through All Pages
            {

                LocTextExtractionStrategy lteStrategy = new LocTextExtractionStrategy(); //Read PDF File Content Blocks

                pcbContent = psStamp.GetUnderContent(intCurrPage); //Look At Current Block

                //Determine Spacing of Block To See If It Matches Our Search String
                lteStrategy.UndercontentCharacterSpacing = pcbContent.CharacterSpacing;
                lteStrategy.UndercontentHorizontalScaling = pcbContent.HorizontalScaling;

                //Trigger The Block Reading Process
                string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfFileReader, intCurrPage, lteStrategy);

                //Determine Match(es)
                List<iTextSharp.text.Rectangle> lstMatches = lteStrategy.GetTextLocations(strSearch, scCase);

                PdfLayer pdLayer = default(PdfLayer); //Create New Layer
                pdLayer = new PdfLayer("Overrite", psStamp.Writer); //Enable Overwriting Capabilities

                //Set Fill Colour Of Replacing Layer
                pcbContent.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK);

                foreach (iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rctRect in lstMatches) //Loop Through Each Match
                {

                    pcbContent.Rectangle(rctRect.Left, rctRect.Bottom, rctRect.Width, rctRect.Height); //Create New Rectangle For Replacing Layer

                    pcbContent.Fill(); //Fill With Colour Specified

                    pcbContent.BeginLayer(pdLayer); //Create Layer

                    pcbContent.SetColorFill(BaseColor.BLACK); //Fill aLyer

                    pcbContent.Fill(); //Fill Underlying Content

                    PdfGState pgState = default(PdfGState); //Create GState Object
                    pgState = new PdfGState();

                    pcbContent.SetGState(pgState); //Set Current State

                    pcbContent.SetColorFill(BaseColor.WHITE); //Fill Letters

                    pcbContent.BeginText(); //Start Text Replace Procedure

                    pcbContent.SetTextMatrix(rctRect.Left, rctRect.Bottom); //Get Text Location

                    //Set New Font And Size
                    pcbContent.SetFontAndSize(BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED), 9);

                    pcbContent.ShowText("AMAZING!!!!"); //Replacing Text

                    pcbContent.EndText(); //Stop Text Replace Procedure

                    pcbContent.EndLayer(); //Stop Layer replace rocedure

                }                   
                pbProgress.Value++; //Increase Progressbar Value

                pdfFileReader.Close(); //Close File                 
            }

            //psStamp.Close(); //Close Stamp Object             
        }

        }
```

Comment: Please read the introduction of chapter 6 of my book "iText in Action - Second Edition" to understand why your question is wrong. You can download this chapter here: http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only writing to your Console:

```
Console.WriteLine(ExtractTextFromPdf(@"C:\temp\MyPdf.pdf");
```

You are not saving the PDF to disk so you can't expect to see any changes in the pdf file. You code should save the modified text to disk:

```
var editedText = ExtractTextFromPdf(@"C:\temp\MyPdf.pdf");
Console.WriteLine(editedText);
SaveTextToPdf(editedText, @"C:\temp\MyPdf1.pdf");
```

Comment: LRNAB: Thanks for your reply. SaveTextToPdf is inbuilt iTextSharp method or need to write custom method? I am new to use iTextSharp library.

Comment: Well I suggest you read the documentation. SaveTextToPdf is just a fake method for showing you the error in your code. Here is a good [resource](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/686994/Create-Read-Advance-PDF-Report-using-iTextSharp-in)

Comment: LRNAB:As per your instruction I am able to create new pdf with edited text but this pdf does not look like orginal pdf. My basic purpose to replace some words without changing the look and feel of the orginal pdf.Can u help me out regard this, your help is heartily appreciated.

Comment: @user1133737 You are extracting the text only so only text will get saved thus removing any images, formatting etc. Take a look at [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?681178-RESOLVED-quot-replace-quot-Words-in-PDF-file-using-iTextSharp). Also the question has been answered I think.